# Makefile error : recipe commences before first target but not recipe or order

Tags: makefile

I wrote some variables in makefile:

```
N_CFLAGS   = -g \
             --strict \
             $(USER_N_FLAG) \ 
             $(USER_INC) \         <-----------ERROR!
             -D$(ALT_DEVICE_FAMILY)    \ 
             -D$(ALT_DEVICE)    \ 
             $(UART_DEFINES)    \ 
             $(ADD_CFLAGS_ARMCC)
```

The USER_INC is defined below:

```
USER_INC :=-Ilib \
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include \
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include/$(DEVICE_FAMILY) \
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include/$(DEVICE_FAMILY)/miscs \
           -I$(F_LIB_DIR) \
           -I$(H_LIB_DIR) \
           -I$(C_LIB_DIR)
```

I used to change all TAB to space.
However it give me another error at the same place ***missing seperate,STOP.
These lines are not orders or recipes and they are not even used.
I dont know why these errors ever happened.

Do you guys have any idea on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the whitespace more visible, and the error becomes apparent:

```
$ cat -TE Makefile
N_CFLAGS   = -g \$
             --strict \$
             $(USER_N_FLAG) \ $
^I^I^I $(USER_INC) \         <-----------ERROR!$
             -D$(ALT_DEVICE_FAMILY)    \ $
             -D$(ALT_DEVICE)    \ $
             $(UART_DEFINES)    \ $
             $(ADD_CFLAGS_ARMCC)$
```

Notice that space between `\` and the newline?  That means the backslash is escaping the space - *not the newline*.

Because the next line (not part of the continuation) begins with a tab, it's interpreted as a command, but we're not inside a rule, so that's an error.

If you can do so, configure your editor to highlight whitespace at end-of-line, and to display tabs distinctively.

Comment: There's no problem having continued lines indented with TAB.  It's only the first character of the logical line (not every physical line) that cares about TAB vs. space.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist - I've rewritten this answer completely now.

Answer (score -2):

Ok I got it

```
USER_INC :=-Ilib \"there is a space"
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include \"there is a space"
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include/$(DEVICE_FAMILY) \"there is a space"
           -I$(LIBS_DIR)/include/$(DEVICE_FAMILY)/miscs \"there is a space"
           -I$(F_LIB_DIR) \"there is a space"
           -I$(H_LIB_DIR) \"there is a space"
           -I$(C_LIB_DIR)
```

But I still dont know why the error happened on that line.
If you want to avoid that annoying error, you can do following:
for example:

```
AAA := $(AAA)"space"\"enter"$(BBB) .......
```

Comment: The error is because the backslash only looks at the next character on the line.  If the next character after the backslash is a newline, then it's a line continuation.  If the next character after the backslash is not a newline (for example it's a space or some other character), then it's not a line continuation.  This is how backslash/newline continuation works in virtually every programming language.  You should figure out how to configure your editor to automatically remove trailing whitespace when you save your file.